# extjs jsonstore post params

Tags: extjs

i'm very new to extjs and i'm trying to make some sense of from what i know from Jquery. I want to have an object to be used application wide as key=>val. I think that using a store is the way to go about it but i can't get it to post any parameters. I have tried dozens of variations to call it but no luck. The code i'm using for now is

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({  
        method: 'POST'  ,
        url: '/LoadLanguage.html',
    }),
    autoload: true,
    baseParams: {
        'code' : code
    },
    root: '',    
    fields: [{name: 'Time', mapping: 'Time', type: 'int'}]                  
});
```

Problem is that the $_POST variable is always empty and the GET is like http://lordos.home.local/LoadLanguage.html?_dc=1305874986764&page=1&start=0&limit=25
I need it to post the parameters cause GET will not do.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what you're doing to please forgive me if this is just not going to work for you.

If you want to have a key=>val storage mechenisim I would suggest the KISS method and use a literal JS object to store / get the data.

```
 // Define a namespace.
 window.MyNamespace = {};

 // Add my config object to hold key => balue
 MyNamespace.config = {};

 MyNamespace.config = {
     key  : 'value',
     key2 : 'value2'
 };
```

Do do an ajax request I would use...

```
Ext.Ajax.Request({
    method:'POST', // This is the default value, here for you to see.
    url:'/LoadLanguage.html',
    params: {
        'post_key1' : 'post_value1',
        'post_key2' : 'post_value2'
    },
    success:function(response) {
         var text = response.responseText;
         MyNamespace.config.language = text;
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, like i said i'm very new to this. What exactly is MyNamespace.MyGlobalObject and how do i use it? If i run you code i get a MyNamespace is not defined

Comment: Sorry, that was a name i just made up. A lot of people make a namespace object to place everything in. You have to define it first by doing something like this: window.MyNamespace = {}; Then you can add your (im guessing this is config)  MyNamespace.config = {};

Comment: thanx a lot, that's what i was aiming for.

Comment: i need some extra help, ho would i access an element inside language. MyNamespace.config.language.save returns MyNamespace.config.language is undefined

Comment: It's because you have to define 'language' as an object: MyNamespace.config.language = {} then you can do MyNamespace.config.language.save = '';

Comment: For times when you just want to setup a long tree like that use Ext.ns('MyNamespace.config.language'); That will take care of creating all the objects for you.

Comment: i have done that already but i still get the same message. I don't want to overwrite any of the elements, just display them. Shouldn't console.log(MyNamespace.config.language) return an object?

Comment: It's 4am here, sorry I have get SOME sleep. Ext.js is just a constant battle - console.log() is your best friend, Good Luck!

Comment: no probs, you've been great help. The problem is that Ajax is async thus the variable populating is off.

Comment: You're trying to get the value out before it's been populated via the ajax request. Put console.log(MyNamespace.config.language) inside of the callback function -> success:function (response) {...}

Comment: i know, it gets populated inside the success. That's why my original post mentioned a store

Comment: The store would make the same type of request (async). Either pass the data down from the server or wait for the request to load. =)